# How can I format 1 000 000 or 25 000 in a textbox C# while typing?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to format the contents of my textbox while typing. I know that I can do this in LostFocus event, but I want it to be done while I am typing. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to implement this?
example textbox Windows calculator

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Keypress event will fire with every keystroke so you can put your formatting code in that event handler to make sure your formatting code is run on any changes to the textbox

Answer (score 0):

During keyboard type event:

- Parse the typed text into an integer and store the value, for ex: `int theinteger`
- Rewrite back to the `textbox.Text` with `string.Format("{0:n0}", theinteger);`

Answer (score -1):

```
public void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
        if ((int)(e.KeyChar) != 8)
        {
            if ((((int)(e.KeyChar) < 48 | (int)(e.KeyChar) > 57) & (int)(e.KeyChar) != 46) | ((int)(e.KeyChar) == 46 & textBox1.Text.Contains(".")))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                if (!textBox1.Text.Contains("."))
                {
                    int iLength = textBox1.Text.Replace(",", "").Length;
                    if (iLength % 3 == 0 & iLength > 0)
                    {
                        if ((int)(e.KeyChar) != 46)
                        {
                            textBox1.AppendText(",");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (textBox1.Text.LastIndexOf(",") == textBox1.Text.Length - 2 & textBox1.Text.LastIndexOf(",") != -1)
            {
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Remove(textBox1.Text.LastIndexOf(","), 1);
                textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Little bit too convoluted but more than that: comma isn't used everywhere, 3 digits grouping is not universal, it's full of magic numbers, cursor position is lost...

Comment: comma and 3-Digit system is used in the calculator, as @DasturchiUZ has asked, thus i implemented the same.